# JavaScript constructor Methods calling other methods in same constuctor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call an object method from another method within the same constructor, and it doesn't seem to be working - I just get the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.uiDisplayOptions()')`.

I'm instantiating the object using using the `new` keyword `var ui = new _ui()`.

Anyone know why it's not working? I've seen examples of this kind of setup being suggested.

Here's the code:

```
function _ui() {
this.uiDisplayOptions = function() {
    var len =  channels[currentChannel].stepsChannel;
    $("select#length option")
        .prop('selected', false)
        .filter('[value="' + len + '"]')
        .prop('selected', true);
    var rand = channels[currentChannel].randomAmtChannel;
    $("select#randomness option")
        .prop('selected', false)
        .filter('[value="' + rand + '"]')
        .prop('selected', true);
    var dir = channels[currentChannel].readDirection;
    $("select#readdirection option")
        .prop('selected', false)
        .filter('[value="' + dir + '"]')
        .prop('selected', true);
}

this.uiSetListeners = function() {
    // Select Channel
    $("#selectChannel0").addClass("green");
    $(".channelselect").click(function() {
        $(".channelselect").removeClass("green");
        $(this).addClass("green");
        currentChannel = $(this).data("channel");
        displayUpdateChannel();
        this.uiDisplayOptions();
    });

    // Select Row
    $("#selectRow0").addClass("red");
    $("#selectRow0").click(function() {
        currentRow = 0;
        $("#selectRow1").removeClass("red");
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });
    $("#selectRow1").click(function() {
        currentRow = 1;
        $("#selectRow0").removeClass("red");
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });

    // Increment/Decrement Selected Row Pattern
    $("#patternInc").click(function() {
        selectPatternRow(1);
        displayPattern();
    });
    $("#patternDec").click(function() {
        selectPatternRow(-1);
        displayPattern();
    });

    // Shift Left/Right Selected Row Pattern
    $("#shiftLeft").click(function() {
        selectShiftRow(-1);
        displayPattern();
    });
    $("#shiftRight").click(function() {
        selectShiftRow(1);
        displayPattern();
    });

    // Handle Row 'Pattern Locks'
    $(".lock").click(function() {
        var step = $(this).data("lockstep");
        switch(toggleLockBit(step)) {
            case 0:
                $(this).removeClass("red green");
                break;
            case 1:
                $(this).addClass("red");
                break;
            case 2:
                $(this).removeClass("red").addClass("green");
                break;
        }
        displayPattern();
    });

    // Handle Channel Length change
    $("#length").change(function() {
        selectCurrentChannelLength($(this).val());
        displayChannelLength();
    });

    // Handle Channel Randomness change
    $("#randomness").change(function() {
        selectCurrentChannelRandomAmt($(this).val());
        displayRandomAmt();
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: Are you missing somethig in this context ?

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: The HTML code is not at all relevant.

Comment: I don't think suggesting this question as duplicate is going to help here, while the topics are indeed similar I do not believe that the suggested question will help OP resolve his problem (it will tell him the why but not the where).

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.uiSetListeners = function() {
    // Select Channel
    $("#selectChannel0").addClass("green");
    $(".channelselect").click(function() {
      $(".channelselect").removeClass("green");
      // this here does not refer to the this of the object being created.
      // it refers to the anonymous function being created in the click call.
      // jQuery is probably invoking this and binding this to undefined,
      // but even if it wasn't then this code would behave incorrectly.

      $(this).addClass("green");
      currentChannel = $(this).data("channel");
      displayUpdateChannel();
      this.uiDisplayOptions();
    });
  });
```

When inside a function the `this`'s value may change. It has it's own binding called a ThisContext and cannot be guaranteed to be pointing at the object you are calling `this` from within (especially with the introduction of `bind`, `apply` and `call`). Inside `uiSetListeners`, `this` is generally bound to the function (which in turn is bound to the object, assuming you are invoking the constructor correctly, and not using any `bind` magic).

However inside your `click`, handler, you are delegating the function to jQuery. jQuery doesn't know about your object so it doesn't bind `this` (or binds it to `undefined`), and it isn't associated with an object by default (as the function is being declared anonymously and not bound to an object). In other words, your `click` handler is pointing to a different `this` than your `this.uiSetListeners` statement is.

The way to fix this is by using a `var that = this;` kind of mechanism. If you take this approach, you should probably define `var that = this` at the top of your constructor function (so others can see what's going on) and replace any incidence of `this` inside of the constructor function with `that`.

This ensures that should another user call your constructor with `call`, `bind` et al, the object will be bound correctly to the supplied `this`.

```
    var that = this;
    that.uiSetListeners = function() {
      // Select Channel
      $("#selectChannel0").addClass("green");
      $(".channelselect").click(function() {
        $(".channelselect").removeClass("green");
        $(this).addClass("green");
        currentChannel = $(that).data("channel");
        displayUpdateChannel();
        that.uiDisplayOptions();
    });
  });
```

Note that ES6 fixes this with the fat arrow notation.

```
this.uiSetListeners = function() {
  // Select Channel
  $("#selectChannel0").addClass("green");
  $(".channelselect").click(() => {
    $(".channelselect").removeClass("green");
    $(this).addClass("green");
    currentChannel = $(this).data("channel");
    displayUpdateChannel();
    this.uiDisplayOptions();
  });
});
```

You should be perfectly able to invoke other methods from within the constructor as long as you remember to take care with your `this`.

It is generally preferable to use `YourConstructor.prototype.methodName` instead, as this will first of all reduce nesting but also uses the prototype chain. Assigning functions to `this` in the constructor does not assign them to the prototype chain, which also means they will be recreated each time a new object is created. You only really need to assign functions to `this` inside of a Constructor if their implementation is dependent on the values passed into the constructor and it is not appropriate to capture those values in the constructor as state on the created object.

Comment: I'll try the prototype method too. I'll only be creating one instance of my object in this case, so that should work fine, and be more efficient, as you suggest.

Comment: Another benefit is inheritance, you cannot extend your class as is unless you use the constructor because the methods you assign in the constructor are not on the prototype chain.

Comment: I can't seem to get the method above to work with the prototype declaration method. I'm happy for the moment to declare the object methods in the constructor, since it works. To put things in context, this is part of a JS simulation of a system that will eventually end up as the Arduino-based firmware for a piece of music hardware, so as long as this part of the system works, I'll leave it as-is.

Comment: Incidentally, that's why I'm referencing lots of global functions and variables. It's common to work this way in the Arduino world, though I'm aware it's frowned upon in Javascript circles.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Arduino systems other than the use of them in my previous employment position. If it works for you, it works. It's just a guideline. No point assigning to the prototype if you don't need the inheritance (but just be wary of the performance benefits)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks very much for all your help, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call a function like this inside a constructor, `this` will refer to global object `window` until  you call your `constructor` function using `new` keyword.

```
var ui = new  _ui();
```

Comment: you can declare your functions outside the constructor function and then call them inside each other. it will work.

Comment: I am making an instance of the object using 'new', exactly as you suggest, me0n.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by your second reply, me0n.

Comment: is the problem that its actually jQuery that's calling the method from inside the constructor, rather than the method being called from outside the object instance?

Comment: exactly! Alex Drinkwater you got the point.

Comment: I can tell you one trick you can define the current scope object in your constructor function on the top like below

Answer (score 0):

refer the current object context on the top of you constructor function.

```
function _ui() {
  var _that = this;
}
```

and refer all current constructor function using `_that` reference.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create multiple answers to the same question - just modify your original answer. @AlexDrinkwater it can be done, and it is a common idiom. See my answer. You need to place `var _that = this;` at the top of your constructor function, *before any usage of `_that`*.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the detailed answer. I will try your suggestion as soon as I get a chance (away from the computer at the moment).

Comment: Apologies also if my posting etiquette isn't great. I Haven't used this forum much, so I'm not quite sure yet how things work.